# Selector for first instance of an element which has been added to the DOM dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target the first instance of an element which is being added to the DOM dynamically once the page is fully loaded. For an element that's included in the DOM on load, I know you can do this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ele').eq(0).text('Element found');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ele">Element</div>
<div class="ele">Element</div>
<div class="ele">Element</div>
```

But how can I accomplish this same thing for elements that are added to the DOM via jQuery?

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
});

addEventListener('load', function () {
  $('.ele').eq(0).text('Element found');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you should use javascript, not jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
});

addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementsByClassName('ele')[0].innerHTML = "Element found";
});
```

Comment: It still won't work and I couldn't understand why he should use `javascript` and not `jquery`

Answer (score 1):

`$.append` is synchronous, so you can just remove the 2nd `javascript` event handler and do like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('.ele').eq(0).text('Element found');
});
```

A better practice here would be to just keep the reference of the first-appended element and just access it:

```
$(function() {
  const $first = $('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append($first);
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $('body').append('<div class="ele">Element</div>');
  $first.text('Element found');
});
```